# How to make PHP run faster?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, import, ram

I'm currently trying to import around 20 million rows of data from a textfile to table. The speed of it is far too slow (plus 20 million isn't the full thing).

Any ways of actually making the process go faster? BTW i run it from phpmyadmin...

```
<?php 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

$selected = mysql_select_db("data",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select data");

$handle = fopen ('text.txt', 'rt');  
while (!feof ($handle))  
{  
    ini_set('max_execution_time',10800);
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);

    list($a,$b,$c)=explode(" ",$buffer);
    $lol = explode(".",$c);
    $rest = substr($c,-5,3);
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


    if($rest == 'COM'){
    echo $a." | ".$b." | ".$c."<br>";
    $sqlquery = "INSERT INTO zonenet (date, domainname, dnstype, nameserver) VALUES('".$date."','".$a."','".$b."','".$c."')";   
    mysql_query($sqlquery,$dbhandle) or die(mysql_error());
    } 
    else {
    //$dnstype = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ".",
//          "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
    $str = str_replace($lol[1],".NET",$lol[1]);
    //$str = str_replace(end($lol),".NET",end($lol));
    echo $a." | ".$b." | ".$lol[0]."".$str."<br>";
    $sqlquery = "INSERT INTO zonenet (date, domainname, dnstype, nameserver) VALUES('".$date."','".$a."','".$b."','".$lol[0]."".$str."')";  
    mysql_query($sqlquery,$dbhandle) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    //dnstype reference @http://en.wikipeda.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types
    $sqlquery1 = "DELETE FROM zonenet WHERE dnstype NOT IN ('A', 'AAAA', 'AFSDB', 'APL', 'CAA', 'CERT', 'CNAME', 'DHCID'`enter code here`, 'DLV', 'DNAME', 'DNSKEY', 'DS', 'HIP', 'IPSECKEY', 'KEY', 'KX', 'LOC', 'MX', 'NAPTR', 'NS', 'NSEC', 'NSEC3', 'NSEC3PARAM', 'PTR', 'RRSIG', 'RP', 'SIG', 'SOA', 'SPF', 'SRV', 'SSHFP', 'TA', 'TKEY', 'TLSA', 'TSIG', 'TXT')"; 
        mysql_query($sqlquery1,$dbhandle) or die(mysql_error()); 

}   
fclose ($handle); 

//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);

    //$net=explode(".",$c);
    //echo $a."-".$b."-".$c."<br>";
    //

    //
    //mysql_query($sqlquery,$dbhandle) or die(mysql_error()); 
?>
```

Comment: What did you implement at the moment? What did you try?

Comment: I just edited my post, and yes it had many crashes when import a large number.

Answer (score 1):

20M records is not that much so this should be easy to optimize:

1. ini_set is not needed within the loop, once is enough
2. Use batch inserts. Right now you do an insert for every single record
3. Process checks before inserting instead of "deleting" wrong records.

Code changed: (untested)

```
<?php

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

$selected = mysql_select_db("data",$dbhandle) or die("Could not select data");

ini_set('max_execution_time',10800);

$allowedDnsType = array('A', 'AAAA', 'AFSDB', 'APL', 'CAA', 'CERT', 'CNAME', 'DHCID', 'DLV', 'DNAME', 'DNSKEY', 'DS', 'HIP', 'IPSECKEY', 'KEY', 'KX', 'LOC', 'MX', 'NAPTR', 'NS', 'NSEC', 'NSEC3', 'NSEC3PARAM', 'PTR', 'RRSIG', 'RP', 'SIG', 'SOA', 'SPF', 'SRV', 'SSHFP', 'TA', 'TKEY', 'TLSA', 'TSIG', 'TXT');
$lookup = array_flip($allowedDnsType);

$values = array();

$handle = fopen ('text.txt', 'rt');
while (!feof ($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);

    list($domain,$dnstype,$nameserver)=explode(" ",$buffer);

    $lol = explode(".",$nameserver);
    $rest = substr($nameserver,-5,3);
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


    if (isset($lookup[$dnstype])) {

        if($rest == 'COM'){
            echo $domain." | ".$dnstype." | ".$c."<br>";
            $values[] = "'".$date."','".$domain."','".$dnstype."','".$nameserver."'";
        }
        else {
            $str = str_replace($lol[1],".NET",$lol[1]);
            //$str = str_replace(end($lol),".NET",end($lol));
            echo $domain." | ".$dnstype." | ".$lol[0]."".$str."<br>";
            $values[] = "'".$date."','".$domain."','".$dnstype."','".$lol[0].$str."'";
        }
    }

    // insert per 200
    if (count($values) > 200) {
        $sqlquery = "INSERT INTO zonenet (date, domainname, dnstype, nameserver) VALUES(".implode('),(', $values).")";
        mysql_query($sqlquery,$dbhandle) or die(mysql_error());
        $values = array();
    }

    //dnstype reference @http://en.wikipeda.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types
}
fclose ($handle);

if (count($values) > 0) {
    $sqlquery = "INSERT INTO zonenet (date, domainname, dnstype, nameserver) VALUES(".implode('),(', $values).")";
    mysql_query($sqlquery,$dbhandle) or die(mysql_error());
}

//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

20 million rows will take time,as the disk limits how many inserts it is actually possible to do in mysql.

My top advice for this is to use prepared statements. Depending on your mysql-driver it would be something like:

```
$driver->prepareStatement("insert into table (`field`) values (?)");
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $driver->bindParam('s', $row->value);
   $driver->execute();
}
```

Depending on the memory on the server the above might crash as you have all rows in the memory at once. This could be solved by streaming the file line by line, but that should be fairly straigh-forward using a function like http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php

Comment: **Do not use this method**. Let the database do what it was designed to do best. Use the MySQL command `LOAD DATA INFILE`, which will be much, much faster.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve I agree. If you simply want to import large amounts of data directly the Load data method, or mysqlimport is a better solution. However this question was tagged with "PHP", based on which I assumed that some PHP-processing might eventually take place during the import

Comment: It will still be faster do processing from a PHP level on the file directly, then import it directly into MySQL.